# How to query spreadsheet column data, matching and summarising values?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to get the total of entries in a column for a particular value.  The values are a number such as 0.5 or 1 and then a code such a H, S, O or WFH.  i.e   "0.5 H"   or "1 S"

It is a absence spreadsheet recording holiday, sickness, appointments and working from home.  One sheet has a row for every day in the year, the columns represent all the staff members.  I wish to be able to query the values under the columns and then summarise that per staff member / per month.

I have googled but not found anything similar enough to put me in the right direction.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Comment: First, please accept my apologies for the several months which have elapsed since you were kind enough to answer.  I was reviewing my catchall email account this week and spotted the notifications that someone had answered.

A santised / cut-down version of the spreadsheet I'm working with is available https://www.dropbox.com/s/lgnxaup35613qxa/Annual%20Leave.ods?dl=0

Comment: No problem. As this question include the google-spreadsheet tag, it's better to create a demo spreadsheet in Google Sheets, share it with anyone with the link to view only and edit the question to include the link. Also you should include what did you try, links to questions that you think that are similar to this owns a brief description about why the answers to those questions doesn't work for you or if you need help to adapt them to your case.

Answer (score -2):

query function might help you:

1. [about](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=ru)
2. [Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#setting-the-query-from-javascript)

Please, provide data sample to get more help.

your query will look like this:

```
=query({A:D}, "select Col1, Col2, sum(Col4) where Col3 = '1 S' group by Col1, Col2")
```

In this sample query formula summarises data in A:D per columns A, B (`Col1, Col2`) and checks the value in column C (Col3) eqwuals '1 S'.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12620529)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've added formula sample.

Comment: In short, there are 2 sheets - 2016 Overview and 2016 Dates - the first sheet does what it says on the tin and summarises the days taken for different reasons for each team member.  The second sheet, this has a column for each team member and I would like a way of summarising how many sick, WFH or holiday days people have.